# ajax jquery does not submit to the database

Tags: jquery

Please friends I need help. When i want to submit a form using ajax, it does not submit to the database but I get the following log messages:

> Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-07 12:39:23 +0300
>   Processing by CommentsController#create as JS   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"9RZGL7SzAwNUx+FsZaRqUYIpTjtPpR8gsq3AfpGTfIE=",
>   "comment"=>{"person"=>"Psquare", "comment"=>"play great music"},
>   "commit"=>"Create Comment"} Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
>
> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template comments/create,
>   application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js,
>   "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text,
>   :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml,
>   :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf,
>   :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:   *
>   "/home/joseph-ubuntu-pc/Ruby Programs/railsApps/ujs/app/views" ):
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
>
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in`find'
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in
>   `find_template'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:34:in`
>   determine_template'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:10:in `render'
>
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in`
>   render_template'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'   actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in`
>   _render_template'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
>
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in`
>   render_to_body'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
>
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in`
>   render_to_body'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'   actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in`render'
>   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels)
>   in render'   activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in`block in ms'
>   /home/joseph-ubuntu-pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in
>   `realtime'   activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in`ms'   actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block
>   in render'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in`
>   cleanup_view_runtime'   activerecord (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in
>   `cleanup_view_runtime'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in`render'
>   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render' 
>   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in`send_action'
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in
>   `process_action'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block
>   in process_action'   activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in`
>   *run*_1159258281710581833__process_action_*4226477895840818250*_callbacks'   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   `__run_callback'   activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`_run_process_action_callbacks'
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   `run_callbacks'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in
>   `process_action'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`block in
>   process_action'   activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
>
>   activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in
>   `instrument'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in`process_action' 
>   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action' 
>   activerecord (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`
>   process_action'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in`process'   actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'   actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in`
>   dispatch'   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in
>   `block in action'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in`call'   actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
>
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in`
>   call'   journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
>
>   journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in`each'   journey (1.0.4)
>   lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in`call'   actionpack
>   (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call' 
>   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in`call'   rack (1.4.5)
>   lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in`call'   actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call' 
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in`
>   call'   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
>   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in
>   `call'   activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in`
>   call'   activerecord (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in
>   `call'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in`block in call'
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in
>   `_run__224644368831049422__call__3598850467178390193__callbacks'
>
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`
>   __run_callback'   activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
>
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`
>   run_callbacks'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'   actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in
>   `call'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
>
>   railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in`call_app'   railties
>   (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
>
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in`
>   tagged'   railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
>
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in`
>   call'   rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'   rack
>   (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`call'   activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'   rack
>   (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in`call'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'   railties
>   (3.2.12) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in`call'   railties (3.2.12)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'   rack (1.4.5)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in`call'   railties (3.2.12)
>   lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'   rack (1.4.5)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in`service'
>   /home/joseph-ubuntu-pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in
>   `service'
>
>   /home/joseph-ubuntu-pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`
>   run'
>   /home/joseph-ubuntu-pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in
>   `block in start_thread'
>
> Rendered
>   /home/joseph-ubuntu-pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb
>   within rescues/layout (0.4ms)

Your help will be appreciated.Thanks.
Joe

Comment: You have a server problem, seems like you are missing a template

Comment: Thank you Shankar for your comment. I reinstalled rails 2 weeks ago. What do you suggest I do ?